# PC-Lint errors when using direct register addressing

Tags: c, embedded, cpu-registers, lint, pc-lint

I have an existing C-code (3rd party source, I can't change it) which will not be accepted by PC-Lint (Version 9.0). The code is running in an embedded environment, Green Hills Compiler is used.

Has anyone know-how on how to configure PC-Lint to accept the code definition?
I have attached only the error message for the first member in the struct.

Here are the defines from header file:

```
typedef struct  
{  
    uint32_t PINSEL0;  // see ERROR message from PCLint, line 153 in LPC23.h  
    uint32_t PINSEL1;  
    uint32_t PINSEL2;  
} LPC_PINCON_TypeDef;


#define LPC_PINCON_BASE           (0xE002C000)
#define LPC_PINCON                ((LPC_PINCON_TypeDef *) LPC_PINCON_BASE)

#define PINSEL_BASE_ADDR    0xE002C000
#define PINSEL0        (*(volatile unsigned long *)(PINSEL_BASE_ADDR + 0x00))


/**************************/

/* function in c-file */

void Port_Init()  
{

  LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 &= ~(3 << 4); //p0.2  

  LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |=  (1 << 4); // 

  LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 &= ~(3 << 6); //p0.3  

  LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |=  (1 << 6); // 

  // etc................  
 }

/*******************************************/

  //    ERRORS from PC-Lint    
  //   **********ERROR MESSAGES**************

  #... (volatile unsigned long *)(PINSEL_BASE_ADDR + 0x00))
   uint32_t PINSEL0;
   LPC23.h  153  Error 10: Expecting identifier  

  #... BASE_ADDR + 0x00))  
   uint32_t PINSEL0;
   LPC23.h  153  Error 102: Illegal parameter specification  

  #... BASE_ADDR + 0x00))
   uint32_t PINSEL0;
   LPC23.h  153  Error 10: Expecting ';'
```

Comment: Why do you use lint at all, when do you are not willing to change the code? It is not a compiler, but an analyzer.

Comment: The SW-project consists of 3rd party code (which I don't want to change) and own written code. If it is possible I want to have lint errors only for my own written code.

Answer (score 5):

An excerpt from the [PC-lint FAQ](http://www.gimpel.com/html/techfaq.htm#q2):

> 2. **How do I tell lint not to complain about my compiler headers?**
>
>    Lint uses the label of "library" header to designate those headers over
>      which a programmer has no control (such as compiler headers).  By default
>      all #includes from a foreign directory, or enclosed within **< >** , are 
>      considered "library."  This can be modified through the use of the `+libclass`
>      option, and further fine-tuned with the  `+/-libdir` and `+/-libh` options.
>      You can then use the `-wlib` , `-elib` and `-elibsym` options to control just those 
>      messages being  emitted from library headers. Compiler options files distributed
>      with PC-lint usually  contain a `-wlib(1)` option which limits lint output from
>      library headers to errors only (suppressing warning and informational messages).

I guess, that should fit your needs. If not, a minimal example that reproduce your warnings would be nice; the stuff above riddles me, since the #define of PINSEL0 is *after* its use as identifier in the struct.

Answer (score 2):

If the `#define PINSEL0 ...` macro definition is active when the `Port_Init()` function is compiled, I can't understand how you aren't getting *compiler* errors. It seems that there must be something (an `#ifdef` or whatever) that's disabling the  `PINSEL0` macro during compilation - it's not necessary (and is harmful) if you're using the `LPC_PINCON_TypeDef` struct to access the registers.

You'll need to make sure that same controlling option/macro/whatever is set when you run the lint step.

Can you show the actual `LPC23.h` file (or point to it on the web somewhere)?  A similar file I've found (http://www.keil.com/dd/docs/arm/philips/lpc23xx.h) uses only the 'direct macro' technique, and doesn't provide the `LPC_PINCON_TypeDef` struct member access technique.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `LPC_PINCON_TypeDef` and the macro `PINSEL0` are from or for different situations. I hope you are allowed to change one or the other, since the definitions are in immediate conflict.
If I assume that the code itself compiles correctly, then both definitions are never used simultaneously within one translation unit, and PC Lint probably/possibly uses incorrect settings.

I think you may not have presented the implicit macro definitions for the compiler to Lint. At least the `__ghs__` macro has to be defined, use the option `-d__ghs__`. And check the manual for further options.

You may want to check the exact files and their inclusion order using the option `-vf` (or for completeness you may use `-vaif` to inspect what search locations Lint uses for locating include files); but careful, the output is quite large and scrolls off the window and even its buffer easily. It's probably best to pipe the output into a file and inspect it afterward.

And though I hesitate to point to my own website, but if you want, take a look at my PDF ["How to wield PC Lint"](http://www.bezem.de/pdf/htwpl.pdf), you'll find simple steps from zero to properly linting your code using PC Lint, with all the options to be set.

If all doesn't help, you'd have to elaborate on the setup you're using and the options for both the compiler and for PC Lint.